# What are the Unique Units, Unique Buildings, and Unique Ability of the DLC Civilizations?

Tags: civilization-5

I've been having trouble gauging whether or not I want to purchase the Civ V DLC, because it's hard to find out how the DLC civs play before purchasing them outright.

What available civilizations are not part of the base game, and what are the unique units/buildings and unique ability of the DLC civilizations?

Comment: I recommend you change this question to be about *all* DLC civilizations, so any future civilizations could also be edited into the answers here.

Comment: @Oak - I've implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Civilization 5 Wiki states the following for [Babylon](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Babylon_(Civ5))

> **Ingenuity**:
>
> Free Great Scientist upon
>   invention of Writing. Double rate of
>   generating Great Scientists throughout
>   the game.
>
> The Bowman replaces the Archer, it is stronger in melee (6 vs 4) and ranged (8 vs 6). The Walls of Babylon replace the walls, they are stronger (7.5 vs 5 defense) and they increase the bombardement damage of the city.

for [Spain](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Spanish_(Civ5))

> **Seven Cities of Gold**:
>
> Gold received
>   for discovering Natural Wonders (more
>   if first to discover). Natural Wonder
>   provide double Culture, Happiness and
>   yields.
>
> The Tercio replaces the Musketman, it is stronger (18 vs 16), has a 100% bonus against mounted units, but is more expensive (140 vs 120). The Conquistador replaces the Knight, but it can found cities.

and for the [Inca](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Incan_(Civ5))

> **Great Andean Road**:
>
> Hill terrain cost
>   ignored. Half improvement cost;
>   improvements on hills free.
>
> The Slinger replaces the Archer, it is weaker in melee (2 vs 4) but it has a chance to withdraw before combat. The unique improvement is the Terrace Farm, which is a farm that can be built on hills and needs no fresh water.

I also found [this official announcement for Spain and Inca from Greg 2K of 2k games](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?100091-Spain-Inca-Unique-Units-Abilities-and-Improvements!) which confirms the information from the Wiki.

Comment: If you update this answer to include what makes the Bowman and Walls of Babylon different from their default counterparts, I will accept it.

Comment: @Raven bowman have 6 strength 8 ranged - compared with the archer's 4/6. Walls of Babylon have 7.5 defense instead of 5, and also increase the damage the city does during bombardment.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Civilization 5 Wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Civilizations_%28Civ5%29) there are two new DLC civilizations since the previous reply: The Danish and the Polynesian.

**[Denmark](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Danish_%28Civ5%29)**

> *Ability Viking Fury*: Embarked Units have extra movement and less
>   movement cost to move from sea to
>   land. No movement cost to pillage
>   improvements.
>
> *Building*: None
>
> *Unit [Berserker](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Beserker_%28Civ5%29)*: Replaces Longswordman. +1 movement and
>   amphibious. (No penalty for attacking
>   from sea or across river.)
>
> *Unit [Norwegian Ski Infantry](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Norwegian_Ski_Infantry_%28Civ5%29)*: Replaces Rifleman. +25% combat bonus
>   and double movement on tundra, snow
>   and hills if forest or jungle is not
>   present.

**[Polynesia](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Polynesia)**

> *Ability Wayfinding*: Can embark and move over oceans immediately. +1 Sight
>   when embarked. +10% Combat Strength
>   bonus if within 2 tiles of a Moai.
>
> *Improvement [Moai](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Moai)* (Easter Island statue): +1 culture, plus
>   additional culture if built next to
>   another Moai.
>
> *Unit [Maori Warrior](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Maori_Warrior_%28Civ5%29)*: Replaces Warrior. -10% combat penalty for
>   adjacent enemies.